# Conditional binding of method to drop down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have dropdown and a function to display progress bar. I have bind the function to dropdown using jquery, its working fine. Problem is, i want to display the progress bar if post back occurs, But its showing always when i select option in any drop down. I have tried to give condition on attribute but its not working. My HTML code is.

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>Perspective :</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchPerspective" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSearchPerspective_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="300px"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>KRA :</td>
        <td>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchKRA" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>

 $(document).ready('select').change(function (event) {
        var chg = $(this).attr('onchange');           
        if (chg != "" && chg != null) {
            ShowProgress();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` does not accept a selector. You want it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function(event) {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){// use document ready    
    $('select').change(function (event) { // now change event
        var chg = $(this).attr('onchange');           
        if (chg != "" && chg != null) {
            ShowProgress();
        }
    });
})
```